# An efficient way to subset a data frame into multiple data frames

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have a fairly large data frame and I'm trying to divide this data frame into multiple smaller ones.
Suppose I have this data frame called df:

```
   Patient   Status    cancer
1        1  treated  melanoma
2        2 deceased  melanoma
3        3 deceased carcinoma
4        4  treated  lymphoma
5        5 deceased  melanoma
6        6  treated carcinoma
7        7 deceased  lymphoma
8        8 deceased carcinoma
9        9  treated  melanoma
10      10  treated  melanoma
```

I want to subset data frames based on the "cancer" column, and store them in their respective object, as follow:

```
  Patient   Status    cancer
1       3 deceased carcinoma
2       6  treated carcinoma
3       8 deceased carcinoma

  Patient   Status   cancer
1       1  treated melanoma
2       2 deceased melanoma
3       5 deceased melanoma
4       9  treated melanoma
5      10  treated melanoma

  Patient   Status   cancer
1       4  treated lymphoma
2       7 deceased lymphoma
```

I've mannaged to write this code, using dplyr's function `filter`, and it does the job, but because my initial data frame is pretty large, looping chokes my computer,

```
factors = c(levels(df[,"cancer"]))
for (i in factors) {
  assign(i, filter(df, cancer == i), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
```

I would appreciate if someone could kindly suggest a more optimized alternative.

Best regards.

Comment: Just use `split`: `split(df,df$cancer)`.

Comment: why did you change your answer to a comment? It was a proper  and correct answer.

Comment: Thank you @nicola, and if i want to save every elelemnt in the retuned list by `split()`, do i have any better options than iterating? i mean: `xx = split(df, df$cancer)`

`for (i in names(xx)) {
  assign(i, as.data.frame(xx[i]), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}`

Comment: Try `list2env`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516325/converting-a-list-of-data-frames-into-individual-data-frames-in-r

Comment: amazing. thank you dear @yarnabrina for your great help.

Comment: @BruceSchardt Because it's certainly a dupe, so I thought it was worth just a comment IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you have data frames for which operations are slow in general consider changing to the data.table framework. You would be surprised of the increase in performance.